# Print enum text instead of value C++

Tags: c++, printing, enumeration

In Form.h I have:

```
enum Direction {
   NORTH = 0,
   SOUTH = 1,
   EAST = 2,
   WEST = 3,
};
```

In Play.cpp I have a method that prints the movement like "PlayerA moved to NORTH"

```
void Play::printMove(Direction dir) {
   std::cout << this->getName() << " moved to " << dir << std::endl;
}
```

Because this printed 0, 1, 2 or 3 I tried:

```
void Play::printMove(Direction dir) {
   std::string moveStr;
   switch (dir) {
      case NORTH: moveStr = "NORTH";
      case SOUTH: moveStr = "SOUTH";
      case EAST: moveStr = "EAST";
      case WEST: moveStr = "WEST";
   }
   std::cout << this->getName() << " moved to " << moveStr << std::endl;
}
```

But this didn't work either. Why? What can I try?

Comment: Reread your C++ book chapter that explains how the `switch` statement works, paying attempt to how your C++ book describes the `break` keyword.

Comment: Also look into look-up tables. A relatively simple table will eliminate the need for the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `break` keyword or else `printMove()` will always result in "WEST". As soon as the computer finds a case that matches, it reads the code that follows all the way through the `switch` statement. The `break` keyword tells the computer to stop reading and continue the program after the end bracket of the `switch`.

```
void Play::printMove(Direction dir) {
    std::string moveStr;
    switch (dir) {
        case NORTH: 
            moveStr = "NORTH";
            break;
        case SOUTH:
            moveStr = "SOUTH";
            break;
        case EAST:
            moveStr = "EAST";
            break;
        case WEST: 
            moveStr = "WEST";
            break;
    }
    std::cout << this->getName() << " moved to " << moveStr << std::endl;
}
```